# Large Dataset Polynomial Fitting Using Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to fit a second order polynomial to raw data and output the results using Matplotlib.  There are about a million points in the data set that I'm trying to fit.  It is supposed to be simple, with many examples available around the web.  However for some reason I cannot get it right.

I get the following warning message:

> RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned

This is my output:

[image: Python Results]

This is output using Excel:

[image: Excel results]

See below for my code.  What am I missing??

```
xData = df['X']
yData = df['Y']
xTitle = 'X'
yTitle = 'Y'
title = ''
minX = 100
maxX = 300
minY = 500
maxY = 2200

title_font = {'fontname':'Arial', 'size':'30', 'color':'black', 'weight':'normal',
              'verticalalignment':'bottom'} # Bottom vertical alignment for more space
axis_font = {'fontname':'Arial', 'size':'18'}

#Poly fit

# calculate polynomial
z = np.polyfit(xData, yData, 2)
f = np.poly1d(z)
print(f)

# calculate new x's and y's
x_new = xData
y_new = f(x_new)   

#Plot
plt.scatter(xData, yData,c='#002776',edgecolors='none')
plt.plot(x_new,y_new,c='#C60C30')

plt.ylim([minY,maxY])
plt.xlim([minX,maxX])

plt.xlabel(xTitle,**axis_font)
plt.ylabel(yTitle,**axis_font)
plt.title(title,**title_font)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the outliers? Maybe excel removes outliers automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The array to plot must be sorted.** Here is a comparisson between plotting a sorted and an unsorted array. The plot in the unsorted case looks completely distorted, however, the fitted function is of course the same.

```
        2
-3.496 x + 2.18 x + 17.26
```

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)

x = (np.random.normal(size=300)+1)
fo = lambda x: -3*x**2+ 1.*x +20. 
f = lambda x: fo(x) + (np.random.normal(size=len(x))-0.5)*4
y = f(x)

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(6,3))
ax.scatter(x,y)
ax2.scatter(x,y)

def fit(ax, x,y, sort=True):
    z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
    fit = np.poly1d(z)
    print(fit)
    ax.set_title("unsorted")
    if sort:
        x = np.sort(x)
        ax.set_title("sorted")
    ax.plot(x, fo(x), label="original func", color="k", alpha=0.6)
    ax.plot(x, fit(x), label="fit func", color="C3", alpha=1, lw=2.5  )  
    ax.legend()


fit(ax, x,y, sort=False)

fit(ax2, x,y, sort=True) 


plt.show()
```

Comment: You're not comparing a sorted and unsorted fit.  You're comparing a line that you're plotting in random order with one that you're not.  Try `print(np.polyfit(x, y, 2), np.polyfit(x2, y2, 2))`.

Comment: Goodness me, would never have guessed that!  Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @DSM true, that could have been misleading. I edited the answer.

Comment: After sorting my plot is still not right.  The same as originally.  I get an error message saying "Polyfit may be poorly conditioned"

Comment: I had to use float64 instead of float32 - no idea why this would be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably using a power basis for data that is displaced some distance from zero along the x axis. If you use the `Polynomial` class from `numpy.polynomial` it will scale and shift the data before the fit, which will help, and also keep track of the scale and shift used. Note that if you want the coefficients in the normal form you will need to convert to that form.