# Scipy curve fitting plots multiple fitted graphs instead of one

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to draw a regression curve through my `x` and `y` data. I'm using the code provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11209147/3764804) answer. The final figure however contains multiple red lines instead of just a single one which looks cluttered. How is this caused and is there a way to just draw a single fitted graph?

[image]

Comment: It connects all the points from each point. Instead `plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")`, try `plt.scatter(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")`

Comment: You're going to have to show some code for us to know how to help. But I suspect what @Naveen pointed out is part of the problem.

Comment: Yes, sorting before plotting the regression curve was the key as demonstrated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42999161/3764804 :)